# How to disable Tab key in typeahead js dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I have a dropdown with suggestions, i have used typeahead ([jquery.typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)) for suggestions. when i start typing in the input box it shows me a list of suggestions,when i press TAB i want to focus on next focusable element but not from the suggestions. I gone through [the existing stackoverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821121/turn-off-tab-for-typeahead-js) there i see that we need to modify in the typeahead source file, there i cannot modify there.

Is there any possibility to override the _onTabKeyed without modifying the typeahead source code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.  The *whole point* of an auto-complete box is so that you can...well... auto-complete.  If you disable that function then why have an auto-complete box?  The example you link to does allow tab-to-next-input when not in "auto-complete" mode.  eg enter "Flo[tab][tab]" and you're on the "view raw" button.   What use would be an auto-complete you can't auto-complete?

Comment: I need the suggestion but considering the accessibility, i am using down arrow to access all the suggestions, But if user press TAB it should go to next focusable element.